# CWinAppEx menu toolbar gets incorrectly resized if application is restored after computer sleeps

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a windows application based on the MFC framework. The Main application is derived from the CWinAppEx class. I have a menu bar defined from a template which is created using the VS resource editor. The issue I am experiencing is that the size of the menu bar is incorrect after the application is restored (i.e. from being minimized to the windows task bar) after the computer has been sleeping.

Usually the menu bar shares the client width of the main frame window. It resizes with the main frame correctly. It also behaves normally after minimizing and restoring the application from the task bar (assuming the OS does not go to sleep). If the application is not minimized prior to the OS sleeping, there is also no issue.

I've searched for similar issues on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but haven't found similar reports.

I've tried calling SetWindowPos(...) directly on the menu bar object while handling the WM_SIZE message of the Main Frame after it gets restored which gives the correct overall size and position, but the menu items aren't positioned correctly after doing so. But this approach seems like band-aid solution and isn't getting at the root of the issue.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this issue.

Comment: _I've tried calling SetWindowPos(...) directly on the menu bar object while handling the WM_SIZE message of the Main Frame after it gets restored_ Good enough, I would say.  MFC is getting very long in the tooth now and I doubt if it's getting much love from MS.

Comment: @PaulSanders thanks for your comment. You may be right! If it's a basic limitation of MFC I would have expected to find similar reports by other developers. I keep wondering if there is some style parameter that would cause this issue - but none of them seem to fit the bill.

Comment: MFC hasn't got big updates for a long time now, but still, components such as frame windows, menu-bars, dialog-bars, rebars etc work really well in almost all cases. You can try creating a new test-project, and you will find that the wizard-generated code works just fine. There must something you do in your code that causes the problems, like the aforementioned sizing, resizing or repositioning. If the test-project works well you can compare the code. Or you can make a copy of your project and start removing stuff until it works as intended.

Comment: Can you repro this issue with a MFC application created from the App-Wizard? I can't see such problems you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The application was generated using the App Wizard but clearly something that the main frame CWnd is doing is having an effect. There just seems to be very little code that actually involves the menu bar and nothing stands out as the culprit.